# Mapping arbitrary unicode alphanumeric characters to their ascii equivalents

Tags: unicode, mapping, ascii

When I encounter arbitrary unicode string, such as in a hashtag, I would like to express only its alphanumeric components in a string of their ascii equivalents. For example,

```
x='€'
```

would be rendered as

```
x='Patriot'
```

Since I cannot anticipate the unicode that could appear in such strings, I would like the method to be as general as possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unicodedata.normalize` method can translate Unicode code points to a canonical value.  Then, run the value through `ascii` encoding ignoring non-ASCII values for a byte string, then back through `ascii` decode to get a Unicode string again:

```
>>> x='€'
>>> ud.normalize('NFKC',x).encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('ascii')
'Patriot'
```

If you need to removed accents from letters, but still keep the base letter, use `'NFKD'` instead.

```
>>> x='€ô'
>>> ud.normalize('NFKD',x).encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('ascii')
'Patriot'
```